# how to get combobox selected item to string

Tags: c#, xaml

how do i get my combobox selected item that are populated from a itemsource to a string so i can use it in my post that are in another void as with `string bolts = comboBox_Copy.Text;` or `string bolts = comboBox.Copy.SelectedItem;` gives `null`

```
     private void boltPatterns()
    {
        {
            try
            {
                string Url = URL_Domain + "resources/bolt-pattern";
                Uri serviceUri = new Uri(Url);
                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    string api = webClient.DownloadString(serviceUri);

                    List<boltPatterns> values =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<boltPatterns>>(api);
                    comboBox_Copy.ItemsSource= values;
                }
            }
```

XAML

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_Copy" DisplayMemberPath="BoltPattern" SelectedItem="{Binding BoltPattern}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bindings (which is a good thing), so you do not need (and in MVVM mostly should not) access the combobox itself.

If you would like to use MVVM, set on your top-level component this `DataContext` to enable binding to code-behind properties:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Then in the code-behind class create a property `SelectedBoltPattern` of type `boltPatterns` (thats how you spelled it in your example). Adopt the SelectedItem binding in your XAML to

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBoltPattern}"
```

Note that this matches the property name.

In code-behind you can access the currently selected item with `this.SelectedBoltPattern`.

Once you get used to binding you might want to do even the easiest applications with a simple MVVM framework like Caliburn.Micro e.g. Those make these things very easy.

Comment: and how exaclty do i then access this.BoltPattern.ToString() as i missing a definition

Comment: That depends on where you bind to. Are you using any MVVM framework? Or is this just XAML with code behind? Is `DataContext` set anywhere? You might just need to define the property `BoldPattern` (hey, you have used it in `SelectedItem="{Binding BoltPattern}"` anyways)

Comment: nope is just xaml with code behind and i haven't settet any datacontext

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen I added the necessary step to enable binding to code-behind. Note that it might be worth starting using Binding without code-behind (leads you to MVVM).

Answer (score 2):

```
string bolts = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: that gives me a nullrefference

Comment: Add it to the combobox selection changed event handler, when they choose an item, the string bolts will update, do some checks to validate that nothing is selected, so an if(comboBox.SelectedIndex > -1)

Comment: You can also check if `comboBox.SelectedItem != null` before assigning it to `string bolts`

Comment: still that do only works inside selection changed event

Answer (score 0):

```
string bolts = comboBox.Text.ToString();
```